# how to finish alertdilog in android

Tags: android

```
protected void shootalertbox(String mymessage) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                getActivity());
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Friend request");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(mymessage);
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.positive_button,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        new sendMesgTask().execute("Friend Request Accpetd",
                                "1", "2", "6");

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Yup", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    }
                });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.negative_button,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        new sendMesgTask().execute("Friend RequestRejected",
                                "1", "2", "7");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

and i m calling like this

```
else if (getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("parmater", 2) == 2) {
            try {

                // 1. get passed intent
                String ntype = myintent.getExtras().getString("message");

                shootalertbox(ntype);

                showContactList();
                // showMap();

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But its not disappear when i click on Accept or reject button still Alert box visible  it comes when i click on Button i want when i click on Yes Or no Button its Alert Box Permanently disappear please help me how i will

Comment: try this `dialog.dismiss();` in dialog button `onClick(..)`

Comment: can you please post your fragment code ?

Comment: ok http://paste.ofcode.org/jXQrCrYFPr5nXbygxT84xq plz check line number 209 am calling that funcation showdilog

Comment: Hello in here. I would like to have AlertDialog showing in UI-BLOCKING mode...., meaning, the application MUST wait for a choice.... is there a practical, and relatively easy way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

you should try this:

```
 dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: there positive  and negative Button  when it should click it should disappear plz check my code]

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on stackoverflow. It's always better to explain what the code does and how it addresses the question. This helps future users.

Answer (score 0):

Use `alertDialogBuilder.dismiss()` in your `setPositiveButton`'s and `setNegativeButton`'s `onClick`

Comment: my class extends public class FragHome extends SherlockFragment like this its actually fragment

Answer (score 0):

you have to perform dismiss method before you calling your asynch task on positive and negative both button.

Or you can dismiss your alert dialog in onPost method of async task.

```
 protected void shootalertbox(String mymessage) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getActivity());
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Friend request");
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(mymessage);
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.positive_button,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                          //try this, you have to perform dismiss method here, because after it you started your asynch task
                             alertDialogBuilder.dismiss()
                            new sendMesgTask().execute("Friend Request Accpetd",
                                    "1", "2", "6");

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Yup", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();

                        }
                    });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.negative_button,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             //try this
                             alertDialogBuilder.dismiss()
                            new sendMesgTask().execute("Friend RequestRejected",
                                    "1", "2", "7");
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();

                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: Cannot refer to a non-final variable alertDialogBuilder inside an inner class defined in a different method error is coming

Comment: did you pass the context in your fragment class ?

Comment: then pass your context instead of getActivity()

Answer (score 0):

use any of this inside onClick()

```
dialog.cancel();
dialog.dismiss();
```

code tobe changerd:

alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.positive_button,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

```
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    new sendMesgTask().execute("Friend Request Accpetd",
                            "1", "2", "6");

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Yup", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                     arg0.dismiss();
                     //arg0.cancel();


                }
            });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.negative_button,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    new sendMesgTask().execute("Friend RequestRejected",
                            "1", "2", "7");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                        dialog.dismiss();
                     //dialog.cancel();

                }
            });
```

Comment: Cannot refer to a non-final variable alertDialogBuilder inside an inner class defined in a different method  eRROR IS COMING

Comment: modify your alertbuilder object to final:

Comment: then also not working there is no method dismiss or cancel int there constructor

Comment: whta the suggesion is shown in IDE..?? is that eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Declare AlertDialog object at class level so it can be access inside OnClickListener :

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private AlertDialog alertDialog;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected void shootalertbox(String mymessage) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Friend request");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(mymessage);
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.positive_button,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        new sendMesgTask().execute("Friend Request Accpetd","1", "2", "6");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Yup", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.negative_button,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        new sendMesgTask().execute("Friend RequestRejected", "1", "2", "7");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: BUt still i my alert box displaying when i click on Sliding Menu Button its come fragment and its visible i have to Permanently finish

Comment: i mean i click from same fragment to same fragment Drawarbar then its visible